# Extract Data for XML and Output to a File to save in a folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

There are two questions actually in this inquiry.
The first has to do with creating an XML file from a SQL query with multiple children records in 3 categories.

The XML Generated seems to concatenate all the children into one value.
I need them to be separated under the same tag.

The second Question is trying to output the resulting file to an XML file in a specific folder on the SQL Server

I have tried several settings for the data but none seem to work such as including [1] and [2], (1) and (2) eliminating the parent on the second value etc. I have don this in MS Access using an XSLT transformation

As far as output is concerned I tried BCP, queryout, OutputFile Output To and a few others. The query states that it was successful but there is no file created.

The SQL table ( FD__Services_from_XML ) looks like this: All Varchar (50) fields

```
  Service_SRI     CovServ_Mod1     CovServ_Mod2
       1               B1               B2
       2               C1               C2
       3               D1               D2
```

The Query generating the XML looks like this:

```
  DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @sqlStr VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @sqlCmd VARCHAR(1000)
--
SET @fileName = 'C:\Users\Steve\Downloads\XML_Export_Test_1.xml'
--
SET @sqlStr = 
'  
Select
  Service_SRI As [SourceRecordIdentifier], 
  CovServ_Mod1 As [ServiceModifiers/ServiceModifier],
  CovServ_Mod2 As [ServiceModifiers/ServiceModifier]
FROM FD__Services_from_XML
FOR XML PATH('ServiceEvent'), ROOT('ServiceEvents')
'
--
SET @sqlCmd = 'bcp "' + @sqlStr + '" queryout ' + @fileName + ' -w -T'
--
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sqlCmd
```

As I mentioned before, I was expecting a file to be created in
    'C:\Users\Steve\Downloads\XML_Export_Test_1.xml'
No File was created.  I do get a Query Executed Successfully Message.

The XML Output I receive looks like this: 
     Notice that the two separate fields Covserv_Mod1 and Mod2 are concatenated

```
<ServiceEvents>
  <ServiceEvent>
    <SourceRecordIdentifier>1</SourceRecordIdentifier>
    <ServiceModifiers>
      <ServiceModifier>B1B2</ServiceModifier>
    </ServiceModifiers>
  </ServiceEvent>
etc ...
</ServiceEvents>
```

The Output I was looking for is:

```
<ServiceEvents>
  <ServiceEvent>
    <SourceRecordIdentifier>1</SourceRecordIdentifier>
    <ServiceModifiers>
      <ServiceModifier>B1</ServiceModifier>
      <ServiceModifier>B3</ServiceModifier>
    </ServiceModifiers>
   </ServiceEvent>
etc ...
</ServiceEvents>
```

SQL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FD__Services_from_XML](
[Service_SRI] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[CovServ_Mod1] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CovServ_Mod2] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I imported the XML Data from an XML file,That looks like this:

```
  <ServiceEvents>
    <ServiceEvent>
      <SourceRecordIdentifier>1</SourceRecordIdentifier> 
      <ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifiers>
        <ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifier>
          <ModifierCode>B1</ModifierCode> 
        </ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifier>
        <ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifier>
          <ModifierCode>B2</ModifierCode> 
        </ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifier>
      </ServiceEventCoveredServiceModifier>
    </ServiceEvent>
    etc. … (1, C1, C2) (3, D1, D2)
  </ServiceEvents>
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of FD__Services_from_XML and some insert statements to show the sample data, so we can reproduce the issue on our local systems?

Comment: I think I have added the additional data requested, If not please let me know and I can add additional information requested